# Does e.g. File.ReadAllText() utilize Windows File Caching?

Tags: c#

Windows File Caching, as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218(v=vs.85).aspx

> By default, Windows caches file data that is read from disks and
>   written to disks. This implies that read operations read file data
>   from an area in system memory known as the system file cache, rather
>   than from the physical disk.

I have a C# app that reads files from disk in a very frequent, rapid manner.  Should I worry about writing my own "file caching" mechanism, or will Windows handle this for me?  When observing my app with Process Explorer, I still notice a lot of disk I/O during operation, even though I'm reading the same static file over and over again. Could it be that the Windows Cache Manager is simply telling the operating system that disk IO is taking place, when in fact the file is being read from the cache in memory?

Comment: You don't need to worry about. This is why 1000 smart developers wrote Windows OS, so you would just do `File.ReadAllText()`. If you want to access file, for example a template that doesn't get modified, yes, you can store it in memory and read memory. But for this, you need to pay attention to caching. For framework <= 3.5 use Enterprise Library 5 caching blocks. For 4.0 - system.runtime.caching or appFabric, etc, etc, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching is enabled by default for filesystem operations in all OSes I'm aware of, Windows included. I'd be astonished if the implementation of `File.ReadAllText` disabled it, because it gives a pretty huge performance benefit.

The filesystem cache is fast, but a custom cache can be purpose-built and therefor much faster.

For instance, `ReadAllText` needs to decode the file into a `string` -- the filesystem cache won't help you there. You can also keep that same instance around, so that all parts of your app accessing it reference the same copy. This gives your CPU's cache a better chance of skipping main memory. Less allocations also means reduced GC pressure.

Do you need your own second layer of caching? Maybe, maybe not -- you should write the simplest code you can first, and then work to optimize it if it's a bottleneck after measuring.